# Problem with drawing an arc on a d3 canvas map

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, canvas

Let's say we have some Basic settings :

```
const canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
const projection = d3.geoEquirectangular()
      .fitSize([canvasWidth, canvasWidth/2], {type: 'Sphere'})
      .precision(0.1);
context = canvas.getContext("2d");
const path = d3.geoPath()
      .projection(projection)
      .context(context);
context.drawImage(someImage, 0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasWidth/2)
```

And then we have a coordinate pair :

```
longitude = 34.9213213
latitude = -23.8229938
```

Now, I want to draw an arc() based on this coordinate pair :

```
context.beginPath();
context.arc(longitude, latitude, 30, 0, 2*Math.PI);
context.strokeStyle = "green"
context.stroke();
context.closePath()
```

In this case, I expect the arc() to be placed in precise geographical coordinates but seems like the arc doesn't understand longitude and latitude,so It takes X and Y values as a horizontal and vertical positions.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A projection takes a latitude longitude pair and converts it from a 3D coordinate space with units measured in degrees to a 2D coordinate space with units in pixels.

You have a projection, I'm assuming that you use it to draw background features with `d3.geoPath()`. By using the path this way you take the background features' latititude/longitude pairs and convert them to pixels. But you aren't using it when drawing your arc, instead you are treating the latitude/longitude pairs as pixel coordinates.

`context.arc()` treats provided x and y as pixel values; it has no connection to the selected `d3.geoProjection` or `d3.geoPath`.

*If `context.arc()` did do geographical projections, you'd still have to specify the projection so that `context.arc()` used the same projection as `d3.geoPath()` - otherwise your features wouldn't overlap properly.*

Instead, project your latitude longitude point to get its location in pixels, and pass that to `context.arc()`:

```
var point = projection([longitude,latitude]); // project a latitude longitude pair to get [x,y] in pixels
context.arc(point[0], point[1], 30, 0, 2*Math.PI);
```